# Mule ESB: How to get the number of files in a FTP directory using MEL?

Tags: ftp, mule

I am looking to get the number of files from a FTP directory which I am able to do it using Java in Groovy Script. I tried using message.inboundAttachments.size() which was not of help. 
Is there a way to get that using MEL (Mule Expression Language)?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about MEL but you can write a java class to do the needful.
For help refer below link
http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/java-ftp-example-calculate-total-sub-directories-files-and-size-of-a-directory

Answer (score 0):

With an open source non Mule ftp connector you can list directories. The result is a collection, so you can use #[payload.size()].

See https://github.com/rbutenuth/ftp-client-connector